# How to calculate (discrete) Pareto distribution. e.g., Probability that someone is in (an arbitrary jellybean giving) secondary sub set.

Tags: probability-distributions

Assuming two equal sized populations (A & B), 20% of group A has been given one or more jelly beans (arbitrary distinction) by one or more people group B.

The subset in group B (B1) who gives away jelly beans follow, a Pareto distribution. So some of the population B:

- a **few** give away one or more jelly beans to **two or more** people in group A
- **some** give away one or more jelly beans, but to **only one** person in group A
- and **many** give **none** away.

**What is the (way to construct an equation to calculate the) probability that a random person from Group B is in sub set B1.**

**Or in a crowd of 100,000 people from group B how many would be in the sub set B1.**

Comment: @willjagy Is that better?

Comment: I happened to look at this, for some reason the software did not inform me of your comment. Happens sometimes. Yes, this will do. You might want to read up on the (bewildering) variety of things called the Pareto distibution http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution, reasons for expecting the Pareto distribution,  and consider asking at CrossValidated in any case. Meanwhile, the word is discrete rather than discreet, which means something else.

Comment: @WillJagy Yeah I got a bit lost trying to work out which of the formulas on the wiki page to use.

Comment: @WillJagy Would it be off topic to ask what the right distribution would likely to be, for distribution of rapists in a population. And would there be a better SE group to ask that under?

Comment: Personally, I think you should let it go, unless you are on a grant for studying this exact question. In that case, I would hire a genuine statistician for a few hours. Many universities with large statistics departments have fairly well organized consulting frameworks, partly because they consult regularly for other departments. Professors are expensive, graduate students less so.